# Launch Visual Studio CODE editor from terminal as root on OS X

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, sudo, visual-studio-code

According to the [documentation off Visual Studio CODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup#_mac-os-x), you can open the editor from terminal by adding the following lines to your .bash_profile on OS X.

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

That just works.

Now the question is, what needs to be done to allow the command to work if you try to launch it with administrator privileges.?

ie:

```
sudo code .
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a sudo version to your .bash_profile

```
sucode () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" sudo open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

This is a problem that has been asked (and answered) in these posts.

[How can I execute a bash function with sudo? (Server fault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/177699/how-can-i-execute-a-bash-function-with-sudo)

[How can I execute a bash function using sudo? (Stack overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448920/how-can-i-execute-a-bash-function-using-sudo)

Comment: Few problems, Vscode doesn't open as root and. You have to specify the file you want to open so its not opening folders.

Comment: This is probably a bug in VS code itself. You can report it here https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List