# Is it possible to run a function specifying user in Bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash.
Now I would like to run a function specifying a user, like,

```
function bash_function() { rm -r "some_directory"; }
sudo -u user bash_function
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448920/how-can-i-execute-a-bash-function-using-sudo

Comment: More likely, `bash_function` doesn't need to run as `user`, but some command in the body of the function does. Rewrite the function to use `sudo` where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Thanks to comments above, function bash_function() { sudo -u "$1" rm -r "some_directory"; } may be a easiest way.