# Executing sed through a function giving unterminated substitution pattern

Tags: bash, macos, sed

Let me begin with what I am trying to do.
I have a sed statement to find a particular line and then change the line below it. For this I first delete the line below it and append the line I want.

```
sed -e '/'"$rootline"'/ {N;s/\n.*//;}' -e '/'"$rootline"'/ a\
'"$1 $linetoadd" <tmpmain >tmpsec
```

Here the first expression finds a line with expression in $rootline and then deletes the next line. And expression 2 adds the line I want to add after the line with $rootline.
Previously I had this in a separate .sh file and when I called the file with sudo (using sudo for some other important operation in the file) it worked perfectly.
Now I am trying to put it in a function and call it through the same .sh file. To call the function with sudo I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230307/7504076). Everything seems to be working fine with regards to the sudo part of the function, but when it comes to the above specified sed operation, I get the following

```
sed: 1: "/root ALL=/ {N;s/
.*//;}
": unterminated substitute pattern  #$rootline='root ALL='
```

Any clue on why I am getting this error?

NOTE: I am working Mac OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. Pretty silly actually.
The way I used to use sudo on the function was to echo the contents of the function to a file. [Got it from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230307/7504076)
And when it was echoing the following code into the file.

```
sed -e '/'"$rootline"'/ {N;s/\n.*//;}' -e '/'"$rootline"'/ a\
'"$1 $linetoadd" <tmpmain >tmpsec
```

It was taking '\n' as a new line character itself and printing a new line instead of "\n" and hence the sed error.